# Rails nested form new association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am currently creating a form with some nested attributes. The relevant parts are that there is a `Sale` model (the master model for the form), a `Vehicle` model (sale has_one vehicle and vehicle belongs_to sale), and a `Registration_number` model (many to many with vehicles, through an assignment table).

I am using the excellent Flexbox JQuery plugin, which allows an existing item to be selected or a new item to be created.

Because I am working with Flexbox, the fields in question are being coded largely in html, bypassing the rails helpers.

When I attempt to create a new registration number (using the field name `sale[vehicle_attributes][registration_numbers_attributes][0][number]`), everything works great, a new registration number is created and it is assigned to the vehicle. When I try to assign an existing registration number (using the field name `sale[vehicle_attributes][registration_numbers_attributes][id]`), however, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find RegistrationNumber with ID=3 for Vehicle with ID=5
```

This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense - the way I see it, Rails should be trying to create this association, not find an existing association? Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I believe this may be related to the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398862/updating-nested-forms-with-existing-data-in-inner-form-using-rails-3, though the accepted answer indicates this was being worked on back in April, and looking at the Github thread it appears that the code has now been merged into Master. Since i'm using Rails 3.1, can anybody indicate if this should now be fixed, and if there is any different syntax I should be using as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by manipulating the intermediate table, here `assignment`.

Insert in your model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments
```

And in your html, append this line:

```
<input name="sale[vehicle_attributes][assignments_attributes][0][registration_number_id]" value="the_registration_number_id_goes_here" type="hidden">
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work... though manipulating the association table directly doesn't seem very "rails-esque". Is what I was trying to do originally not supported?

Comment: Marked as correct answer as this clearly answers the question, but would still be interested in opinions on how proper this method is.